# Can't configure to make the nvim-dap working for Rust development

Tags: rust, neovim

I have been trying to setup for debugging Rust for a while and I couldn't make it right. I have tried multiple stuff but it just never works anyway. When I tried to start a new session, it just runs the executable file and ends the session without let me try to debug it. That's useless.

Here's the video to demonstrate the error. Here I have run `rustc demo.rs` so I already had the demo executable. I just can't run the debugger itself.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I7WuyZi3ewYzq3_8XB9sHauHCgTICEXr/view?usp=sharing

I use nvim-dap for main debugging and also rustaceanvim, which is a new fork of rust-tools itself (since rust-tools is archived anyway). Rustaceanvim said that

`This is a filetype plugin that works out of the box, so there is no need to call a setup function or configure anything to get this plugin working.`

So that's why I didn't setup anything for rustaceanvim except for some keymappings. I just mainly configure nvim-dap itself like this.

```lua
local dap = require("dap")
dap.adapters.codelldb = {
    type = "server",
    host = "127.0.0.1",
    port = "${port}",
    executable = {
        command = "$HOME/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/codelldb",
        args = { "--port", "${port}" },
    },
}

dap.configurations.rust = {
    {
        name = "Launch",
        type = "codelldb",
        request = "launch",
        program = function()
            return vim.fn.input("Path to executable: ", vim.fn.getcwd() .. "/target/debug/", "file")
        end,
        cwd = "${workspaceFolder}",
        stopOnEntry = false,
    },
}
```

No matter what I try, the behaviour is still the same.

Also here's my neovim config: https://github.com/imindMan/arch-config/tree/master/config/nvim.

Comment: FWIW, I'm running into this too after switching from rust-tools; it'd been some months, but my DAP config used to work. After switching to rustacean, I removed my manual DAP config for Rust (per the docs) and started getting this (googling the error led me here). I set a breakpoint, then run `RustLsp debuggables`, pick the top/only test command, then get the error. Just running in a standard multi-crate workspace, using regular ol cargo for things. `codelldb` installed via Mason.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using nvim-dap directly, to manually configure the debug adapter client, and not rustaceanvim.

rustaceanvim has a `:RustLsp debuggables` command that queries rust-analyzer for debug targets and builds them before starting a debug session.
They should show up when running `DapContinue` too, if found after the LSP client's startup.
Afaik, this only works with cargo projects though.

If you're using `rustc`, you should look at the [command line arguments documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/command-line-arguments.html).
Perhaps

> `-g`: include debug information

will help.

Comment: well I have tried that method also. If you just use the `:DapContinue` it will show up the error that I didn't config anything for dap to run rust. I guess maybe there's an error in my lspconfig file:
```vim.g.rustaceanvim = {server = {on_attach = on_attach}}```.
Which will eventually rewrite entire rustaceanvim config, including the dap itself (i guess). But I need it anyway so I don't know how to fix this.
Btw if there's no config for the dap itself and I just run `:RustLsp debuggables` it will show `Multiple compilation artifacts are not supported`. What should I do now?

Comment: As I said, rustaceanvim (and rust-analyzer) will only pick up cargo projects. Have you tried `rustc -g demo.rs`?

Comment: Well I have tried and I haven't achieved anything yet

Comment: I don't know what to say.

I just

- copied your DAP config
- changed the `executable.command` to use my codelldb installation
- Ran `rustc -g demo.rs`
- Added a breakpoint
- Ran `:DapContinue`
- Selected the file
- And it stopped at the breakpoint.

Either you're not compiling with debug information, or there's something wrong with your `codelldb` installation.

Comment: I have installed the codelldb properly. But maybe there's an error there. Your case works, but in my case, I can't 1) connect to rustaceanvim dap config 'cause dap doesn't get the configuration 2) just run, never stop to me. I will try to clear up my neovim a little bit then.

Comment: Again, rustaceanvim's debuggables feature *only works with Cargo projects*. Based on your description, you are not trying to debug a Cargo project. You are trying to debug a *standalone file*.

If you want to use rustaceanvim for debugging, you need to `cargo init` to initialise a Cargo project. This will create a `src/main.rs`, which you can use `:RustLsp debuggables` on.

In order to debug standalone files, you need to compile them with debug information (with the `-g` option), and configure nvim-dap manually. Based on the video, your executable is *not* compiled with debug information.

Comment: Sorry for a little bit late (I still can't figure out) but I have to clarify you something. I HAVE TRIED on a cargo project and it just doesn't work. It works on a small stand-alone cargo project without any other packages added to it, but it just shows out random assembly script. And when I get on multi-package cargo, it just keeps showing "Multiple compilation artifacts are not supported".

Comment: I mean, somehow I have figured out for rustaceanvim works a little bit but it still can't help me at anything.

Comment: "Multiple compilation artifacts are not supported" sounds like it's coming from rust-analyzer. See [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/12645) for example.

> "but it just shows out random assembly"

Maybe try with [nvim-dap-ui](https://github.com/rcarriga/nvim-dap-ui)? nvim-dap is very minimal.

Comment: Thanks for that bro :)) It works finally to me.

Answer (score 0):

That works for me now, after a long discussion anyway. If you ran into some troubles quite like me, here are some ideas hopefully can  help you a little bit:

- Remove everything manually config for dap, except the dap.adapters (which is pretty useful for codelldb). Also use codelldb because rustaceanvim recommended to use it. Remove nvim-lspconfig stuff and using autocmd for the lsp keybindings instead of just configuring every single adapter manually.
- Don't set up everything for rustaceanvim unless you need some. That will just work out of the box with no configuration anyway. Just believe in rustaceanvim, it won't cause you any troubles.
- Update neovim to the latest version (>= 0.10.0).
- Check if your Rust project looks good.
- Try to refresh and configure everything behind-the-hood, e.g. rust-analyzer, well.

For more information, I think my neovim config should work to you: https://github.com/imindMan/arch-config/tree/master/config/nvim